# Deserialize binary array into the correct data type based on type described in the array [c++]

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to deserialize/unpack data from a byte array `transmission_buffer` of fixed size into one of many user defined structs of varying sizes. The first byte of `transmission_buffer` and also the first byte of all the structs is an unique id `pkg_type` which will correspond to one struct.

On the other end of the system, `memcpy` was used to copy the content of one of the user defined structs to a binary array and then transmitted.

```
struct PackageTypeA {
    uint8_t pkg_type;
    uint8_t content1;
    uint16_t content2;
};

struct PackageTypeB {
    uint8_t pkg_type;
    uint8_t content;
};

uint8_t transmission_buffer[64];
```

The information of the corresponding `[struct]<--->[pkg_type]` will be available in some form or another.

```
enum PackageType : uint8_t {
    PackageTypeA = 2,
    PackageTypeB = 66
};
```

I'm hesitant to using third party libraries since the code is ran on microcontrollers, and the reason for writing a binary application layer protocol in the first place is to reduce package sizes and protocol overhead.

One way to get this working is to instantiate all the structs and copy the data over to them but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution with less duplication of code and unnecessary data allocation.

Comment: `memcpy()` is usually the way to go for something like this. Type punning via casts or unions quickly get into [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) territory. And compilers are usually pretty good at optimizing it at high(er) optimization levels.

Comment: Btw; using a third-party library doesn't necessarily imply compromising on performance.

Comment: Try not to include `uint8_t pkg_type;` in the struct, but in the serialized data, it has no usage in the application only for serialization

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks for the answer. I expect to use `memcpy()` in the end, but then I guess the memory would already have to be allocated with the correct data type. So what I was wondering is if there could be solution (maybe involving templates) so that I would not need to instantiate a lot of structs that would probably be unused.